# Is updating codeigniter db-session data clientside via ajax possible?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, session

I'm using codeigniter with encrypted sessions in the database and I'm using a twitter bootstrap modal to update some user details in a form.

I use jquery validation on the form and in the submitHandler I post the data via ajax and close the modal.

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
document.getElementById("edit-profile-submit-button").disabled = true;
$('.modal-ajax-loader').show();
    $.ajax({
        type: $(form).attr('method'), // 'Post'
        url: $(form).attr('action'), // 'profile/edit_basic_details'
        data: $(form).serialize(),
        success: function(data, status){
            $(form).html(data);
            $('.modal-ajax-loader').hide();
            setTimeout(function() { $('#edit-profile-details').modal('hide'); }, 2000);
        },
        error: function(data, status) {
            $(form).html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

and here is the model function called from the controller with the same name,

```
function edit_basic_profile() {
    $screenname = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('screenname'));
    $firstname = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('firstname'));
    $lastname = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('lastname'));
    $email = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('email'));
    $bio = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('bio'));

    $data = array(
        'screen_name' => $screenname,
        'first_name' => $firstname,
        'last_name' => $lastname,
        'email' => $email,
        'bio' => $bio,
    );

    try{
        // Run the update query
        $this->db->where('profile_id', $this->session->userdata('profile_id'));
        $this->db->update('profiles', $data);

        // Let's check if there are any results
        if($this->db->affected_rows() == 1)
        {
            // Setup the session information for the user
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            return true;
        }
        // If the previous process did not update rows then return false.
        error_log("profile_model, edit_basic_profile(): There were no affected rows");
        return false;
    } catch(PDOExceprion $e) {
        error_log("profile_model, edit_basic_profile(): ".$e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

I can update the values that changed on the page in the submitHandler also and of course the session on the server is updated in the model.

```
$("#profile-screenname").html($(screenname).val());
$("#profile-bio").html($(bio).val());
```

The problem is when I open the modal again it grabs the user details from the session data in the browser cookie and grabs the original data unless the page has been refreshed after the first update.

(form data is loaded like this);

```
<input type="text" class="input-large" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" value="<?php echo $this->session->userdata('first_name'); ?>">
```

`"<?php echo $this->session->userdata('first_name'); ?>"` on the second time i open the modal before any page refresh loads the old data.

Comment: Just set update your `session` with the new values. Use `$this->session->set_userdata('name', value)`. This will update your current session and your model will also get the updated session the next time.

Comment: When I call the method on the server in ajax, I update all the session data as you do but it just doesn't update it on the client

Comment: Show me some code where you do it. Your `model`?

Comment: How are you fetching the new session data after you've updated it? What do you return from your controller back to the JS?

Comment: I return a string of html that creates a twitter bootstrap alert (http://cssdeck.com/labs/twitter-bootstrap-alerts-and-notifications) that replaces the form data then the form closes after 2 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you just need to call an ajax url which updates/sets new session data:

```
   HTML+JS 
       ---> Ajax call
          ----> $this->session->set_userdata('key','new-value'); 
            ----> session and db updated.
```

Done.

Also notice and change all these:

```
$screenname = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('screenname'));
```

to this:

```
$screenname = $this->input->post('screenname',true);
```

which is exactly the same result

Comment: The profile_model function does that but its not updated on the client, any reasons for this?